# When is kallsyms created in the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Where is the `kallsyms` created in the `start_kernel` function? I mean we have lot of function calls in the `start_kernel` function. Is it there that `kallsyms` is created. If not,can you please point out in which function call is it created.

And is it possible to use `kallsyms` during early bootup process i.e.,Can we create `kallsyms` before say `setup_arch` function of `start_kernel`?
It is for ARM architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the configuration option CONFIG_KALLSYMS is enabled, the kallsyms feature shall be enabled. However, note that the it is a proc file and the /proc/kallsyms shall be created when the kernel boots up. The /proc/kallsyms shall contain all functions of the kernel.

start_kernel() takes care most of the Linux kernel initializations. This in turn uses the routines like setup_arch which is an architecture based set-up function that performs CPU specific initialization.